# Receiving email notification from smartd (smartmontools)

Tags: monitoring, system-administration, hard-drive

To get information about my HDD drive condition, I configured smartmontools daemon (through smartd.conf) like this:

```
dev/sdb -I 194 -a -o on -S on -s (S/../.././03|L/../../6/04) \
    -m sys@example.com -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

Also, by adding “-M test”, I tested email notifications and received test email message.

As you see, each morning my HDD is short tested, but I didn’t receive any email notification about test results.

Probably, notifications are sent when something is getting wrong, am I right on this point? I mean, is it normal not to receive anything if tests are passed ok?

Right now my drive reports OK status with `smartctl -H` command. I use Debian Etch and Sendmail.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know about `-M test`, you have obviously found the chapter about the `-M` option in the documentation. In the same chapter you will find:

```
exec  PATH  -  run the executable PATH instead of the default mail command,
               when smartd needs to send email.  PATH must point to an
               executable binary file or script.
```

The important word being **"instead"**. If `smartd-runner` doesn't send out mail by itself, you will not be sent any messages.

What does `smartd-runner` do anyway? I'm not familiar with that script.

To answer your question: no mail is sent when there are no errors to report:

```
once - send only one warning email for each type of disk problem detected.
       This is the default.
```